# How long my app be alive in heroku free package?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I just deployed a Node.js app in Heroku. I use their free package. Now wonder how long they keep my application live, if I don't touched it?

Comment: use to be one hour inactive = dyno rolls off to suspended state.. wake up from suspend ie first request to inactive dyno will then require 10+ seconds to wake/restart and ur back in biz for another hour. UX wise , the page-load wait time is very expensive ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just scrolled their [free plan limits page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits), and they don't specify anything related to the life in years of your app. The only actual limits seem to be the performance, the frequent dyno restart procedures and the maximum amount of your git HEAD.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot.